# How to create an Empty of type Image and assign a picture with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, image

How can an Image-Empty be done with Python?

And how to set an image file on it? `Object.data` is `None` for empties, and there is no `.image` property on the object level either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An Empty is created like a regular Object, but with `None` for its data:

```
empty = bpy.data.objects.new("My Empty", None)
```

It can be linked to the current Scene like any other object:

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.objects.link(empty)
scene.update()
```

The origin is set using the standard `.location` property (you may also use `.matrix_world.translation`):

```
empty.location = (1, 2, 3)
```

To make this Empty an Image-Empty, change its `.empty_draw_type` property to `IMAGE`:

```
empty.empty_draw_type = 'IMAGE'
```

An Image datablock is then assigned to the Object's `.data` attribute!

```
img = bpy.data.images.load("path/to/image.png")
empty.data = img
```

Other properties available for Image-Empties are (UI / Python):

- Transparency / `Object.color[3]`
- Image Offset / `Object.empty_image_offset`
- Image Size / `Object.empty_draw_size`

BTW: You can change the RGB colors (`.color[0:3]`) of the object to tint the Image, which is not possible via the interface!